# why the keyof word in TypeScript behaves different in 2 `type defination`s?

Tags: typescript

why the `res1` can't know its type is `number` as the `res2` does?

```
interface P {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
const people: P = {
  age: 30,
  name: 'Peter',
};

type T = keyof P
type Fn1 = (p: P, t: T) => P[T]
type Fn2 = <P, T extends keyof P>(p: P, t: T) => P[T]

const fn1: Fn1 = (p, t) => {
  return p[t]
}
const fn2: Fn2 = (p, t) => {
  return p[t]
}

const res1 = fn1(people, 'age');
const res2 = fn2(people, 'age');
```

Comment: The result is, the type of `res1` is `string|number`;   while `res2` is `string`

Comment: The difference here is `keyof P` versus `extends keyof P`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all lets change definition of `fn2` so we can understand importance of type argument. And we do not confuse ourselves with `T` which is `keyof P`.

`type Fn2 = <P, Tx extends keyof P>(p: P, t: Tx) => P[Tx]`

Generic version of function always has generic type arguments as extra arguments to existing function that helps compiler resolve types. `fn1` has no type arguments, in this case compiler cannot distinguish between `fn1(people, 'age') and fn1(people, 'name')`.

Expanding fn1 in compile time, 
`(p: P, key: "age" | "name") => p['age' | 'name']` there is no generic argument available for compiler to store which key is passed. Type Arguments are like variables which compiler can store information that will be useful in further compilation.

But for fn2, `fn2(people, 'age')`'s type argument is as follow,

`<P, 'age'>(p: P, 'age': 'age' | 'name') => p['age']`, here `Tx` as generic argument is 'age' which compiler knows at compile time and it can store this information along with function which helps compiler resolve `p['age'] as`number`.

Answer (score 1):

If we rename `type T = keyof P` to `type Keys = keyof P`, we see an error in this line:

```
type Fn1 = (p: P, t: T) => P[T]
                     ~~ Cannot find name 'T'.(2304)

// but this line remains fine
type Fn2 = <P, T extends keyof P>(p: P, t: T) => P[T]
```

This is because `T` in `Fn2` is a **type parameter** whereas `T` in `Fn1` is a **reference to a type alias** (revealed when we later rename it to `Keys`).

The type of a type parameter is lazy-bound, just like value of a parameter in a function is only known when the function get called.

But the type of a type alias is eager-bound if possible, just like when you declare a `const` variable, its value is already known at initialization.

Thus the `ReturnType` of `Fn1` is already known to be `string | number` at declaration, while that of `Fn2` is unknown until it's called and **instantiated** somewhere with a concrete type given to type parameter `T`.

Check it out in the [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=25&ssc=28&pln=24&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArIN4FgBQzkhwC2EAXMgM5hSgDmA3LvnLWQQK5EBG0jOAvrgQB7EFWQAHCMIkAbNugC8mJshZsAzAAYANKsIlyAclQRIUI3oF9cYAJ5TkAFWTKA1hDvCYaWw5QAYiAAjK7IABQS5Kg6yGDkTgCUrgB8aADaTgC6fo5BAExhADwxzsgQAB6QIAAmFMgeXj6oKZHRsfHOyYppqJk5OEKi4jAh5EGhypEd3WnYeMhQZuxQIJLpYAOCOCJiYMij+eMghVMSM6kqC0tgK2sSG1u4Q3uLEBSTByGR0nIQsUZ1EZEnxduIlhRTl98j8ZPIAUCQc8cPZHAAlMyfDG3VZOfxFCYpXIobFQ7F3PFSAknFJAA)

```
type Ret1 = ReturnType<Fn1>   // string | number
type Ret2 = ReturnType<Fn2>   // unknown
```